# ActivityIndicator doesn't stop animating nor removes from superview in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to implement `UICollectionView` and show images.  I am using `SDWebimage` which works perfectly in tableviewcells but when i tried to use it in `UICollectionviewCell` it doesn't stop and remove activityindicator.  It does place the placeholder image if there is no downloaded image. I am not sure what is the difference between tableviewcell and collectionviewcell that might cause this problem.

Here is the code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"personImageCell";

    PersonCollectionViewCell *cell = (PersonCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *imgURL=[person.imageurl stringByAppendingString:@"?maxheight=300&maxwidth=400"];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(cell.ivPersonImage.frame.size.width /2, cell.ivPersonImage.frame.size.height/2);
    [cell.ivPersonImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached){
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"activity indicator should be removed");
    }failure:^(NSError *error){
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        cell.ivPersonImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    }];


    [cell.ivPersonImage addSubview:activityIndicator];
    return cell;
}
```

UPDATE:

When i do `NSLog(@"activity indicator should be removed %@,activityIndicator);`

I get this output:

```
 activity indicator should be removed <UIActivityIndicatorView: 0xa520ab0; frame = (65 90; 20 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0xa520b60>>
```

It shows that `UIActivityindicator` is hidden but it is still showing on top of the image

Comment: I would like to know why the down vote?  Thanks!

Comment: So you don't see downloaded image? Or image is not downloaded and that is why activity indicator is not removed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I see the image and get the activity indicator on top in some cells not all and in somes cells the activity indicator is frozen

Comment: Try to place this line `[cell.ivPersonImage addSubview:activityIndicator];` before setting image in `setImageWithURL...`

Comment: @Nekto Thanks for the reply but that didn't work.  The weird part is when the image is cached and placed in the cell the activity indicator does stop and gets hidden only when the image is downloaded then i the indicator is net being hidden.

Comment: added some updates to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you are reusing cell so there are more then one `UIActivityIndicatorView`s.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"personImageCell";

    PersonCollectionViewCell *cell = (PersonCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Person *person = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *imgURL=[person.imageurl stringByAppendingString:@"?maxheight=300&maxwidth=400"];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [cell.ivPersonImage viewWithTag:10];
    if (activityIndicator) [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    activityIndicator.center = cell.ivPersonImage.center;
    activityIndicator.tag = 10;

    [cell.ivPersonImage addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [cell.ivPersonImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached){
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"activity indicator should be removed");
    }failure:^(NSError *error){
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        cell.ivPersonImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You got it right on the money! Thank you very much!  I wouldn't never think this is the issue.  I was doing nslog's but in the wrong places.  When i put nslog right before return cell it showed some cells with two activityindicators.  The only thing i had to do is cast the UIActivityIndicatorView when i was doing [cell.ivPersonImage viewWithTag:10] The thing that it's weird that with tableview it works perfectly.  I guess collectionview has a bit of a different mechanism. Again many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm....this is weird..can you try to make sure the activityIndicator is working on the main thread -

```
[cell.ivPersonImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        }
        NSLog(@"activity indicator should be removed");
    }failure:^(NSError *error){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
        }
        cell.ivPersonImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    }];
```

I suspect it is not, that is why it is not stopping its animation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was just able to try it and still the same problem.  It is something in the implementation of uicollectionview because with uitableview it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you also put the declaration of activityIndicator and startAnimating in the main thread by dispatch_async. I had a similar problem where the activityIndicator just won't go away. I solved it by making sure all UIKit is processed in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Create the activity indicator in the ViewDidLoad of current View Controller

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView      alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 225, 20, 30)];
[spinner setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.color = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
```

Use below code right in the beginning of the function which leads to the activity

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating:) toTarget:selfwithObject:nil];
```

Declare these two methods for starting and stoping the Animation

```
-(void)threadStartAnimating:(id)data
{
[spinner startAnimating];
}


-(void)threadStopAnimating:(id)data
{
[spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

Please give feedback as this code is working fine in my own project